# Match a specific pattern after first match is found and correlate columns between them

Tags: awk

I need to find the difference in timestamps between two related lines in a file that do not share a common identifier. For example:

1. text
2. 2018-01-29 15:05:11,592 Validating control...
3. text
4. text
5. text
6. 2018-01-29 15:05:12,725 Done validating control.

Since there is no unique identifier for each validation process, I need to:

1. First match a line with "Validating control..."
2. Save the timestamp to an array
3. Match the next line in file that contains "Done validating control."
4. Save the timestamp

I have a function to compute the difference in times- I am having a hard time 
parsing out and correlating each duo of validating/done validating lines. Although there will be hundreds of each of those lines, they always occur in sequence and are processed serially. So I always know that when I find "validating", the next occurrence of "done validating" (no matter how far down) will correspond to it.

I was thinking I could parse out all the lines independent of one another (all the "validating" into file A and all the "done validating" into file B) and then correlate line-by-line. Would that be the best approach or is there a way I can do this without generating additional files?

Comment: Does it have to be with `awk` ? How big is the input file ?

Comment: Preferably with awk, yes since I am integrating into a larger awk script that parses logs anywhere from a couple Mb to ~3 Gb. But I can always call bash/sh from within the Awk script should that prove ti be more effective.

Comment: gotcha. I have added a bash script. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

creates a time stamp pair from the matched lines

```
$ awk 'BEGIN                    {FS=OFS=","} 
       /Validating control/     {s=$1} 
       /Done validating control/{print s,$1}' file

2018-01-29 15:05:11,2018-01-29 15:05:10
```

perhaps makes sense to include time delta computation in `awk` as well.

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN                   {FS=OFS=","} 
       /Validating control/     {s=$1} 
       /Done validating control/{gsub(/[:-]/," ",s); 
                                 gsub(/[:-]/," ",$1); 
                                 print mktime($1)-mktime(s)}' file
```

however, your data is in reverse time (ends one second before it starts) so the result will be negative seconds.

If the number following the seconds is part of the time stamp, perhaps this will be better

```
$ awk -F'[, ]' '/Validating control/{s=$1":"$2;ms=$3} 
           /Done validating control/{t=$1":"$2; 
                                     print s ms,t $3; 
                                     gsub(/[:-]/," ",s); 
                                     gsub(/[:-]/," ",t); 
                                     print (mktime(t)+($3/1000))-(mktime(s)+(ms/1000))}' file

2018-01-29:15:05:11592 2018-01-29:15:05:10725
-0.867
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I must have copied an earlier line by mistake. I've updated the time values.

Answer (score 3):

With bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r a b c d e; do
  [[ "$c $d" =~ Validating\ control... ]] && echo "$a $b"
  [[ "$c $d $e" =~ Done\ validating\ control. ]] && echo "$a $b"
done < file
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r a b c d e; do
  [[ "$c $d" =~ Validating\ control... ]] && start="$a $b"
  if [[ "$c $d $e" =~ Done\ validating\ control. ]]; then
    stop="$a $b"
    echo "$start"
    echo "$stop"
  fi
done < file
```

Output:

```
2018-01-29 15:05:11,592
2018-01-29 15:05:10,725
```

Comment: I had overlooked that the question is tagged "awk" only. But maybe it'll help with awk.

Comment: With awk: `awk '/Validating control.../{start=$1 FS $2}; /Done validating control./{stop=$1 FS $2} END{print start; print stop}' file`

Comment: Btw: with GNU sed: `sed -En 's/^([^ ]+ [^ ]+) (Validating control...|Done validating control.)/\1/p' file`

Comment: No problem. I only chose awk because that's what my original script uses but if it gets the job done and can be integrated into the script I dont have any issues. Bash solution is nice though. Will be trying the awk suggestions first and see what works best. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one in GNU awk which calculates the time differences too. The example run is with the same data twice:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="[- :,]" }          # set FS to get the timestamp parts
/alidating/ {                  # if matched
    if(a!="") {                # read the latter value and convert to epoch time:
        b=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)+($7/10^length($7))
        print b-a              # calculate time difference
        a=b=""                 # reset vars for the next pair
        next                   # skip to next record
    }                          # below the former of two values is processed:
    a=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6)+($7/(10^length($7)))
}' file file                   # use same test data twice
0.867
0.867
```

The `+($7/10^length($7))` handles the fraction part, for example 0,592 would be converted 592/10^3 = 592/1000 = 0.592, 0,1 would convert 1/10 = 0.1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Following shows a script where you can save the output to an array in `bash`.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Use sed to print only the relevant lines.
# This also reduces the number of lines to be processed by while loop
sed -n '/Validating control.../,/Done validating control/{//p}' inputFile.txt > /tmp/input_sedVersion.txt

declare -a arr1=()
declare -a arr2=()
i=0
while read -r _date _time _state
do
    if [[ "$_state" =~ Validating ]]; then
    arr1[$i]="$_date $_time";
    else
    arr2[$i]="$_date $_time";
    ((i++));
    fi
done < /tmp/input_sedVersion.txt

echo "arr1: ${arr1[@]}"
echo "arr2: ${arr2[@]}"

# Code do something with these arrays
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
arr1: 2018-01-29 15:05:11,592 2018-01-29 15:10:11,592 2018-01-29 15:15:11,592
arr2: 2018-01-29 15:05:10,725 2018-01-29 15:10:10,725 2018-01-29 15:15:11,725
```